# Error initializing output stream ffmpeg on Rasbpi converting jpg to video

Tags: ffmpeg, libx264

I have a folder with thousands of jpgs at 1024x768 that I want to convert into a single video for playback.

The error I get is `Error initializing output stream 73:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #73:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height Conversion failed!`

Here's my input `$ ffmpeg -i Timelapse/*.jpg -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 0 output.mkv -y`

What is strange is it errors on a specific numbered output stream. It seems to be either 71:0, 72:0, or 73:0. I thought it was something wrong with the file it is attempting to process in the given stream but the resolution is all the same (as I've seen errors when its not divisible by 2). I've deleted the 71st-73rd image in hopes it was somehow messed up but that doesn't help either. I've ensured my libx264 is installed correctly as well.

Any suggestions?

Terminal output example

[image: Terminal output example]

Comment: For next time please just copy and paste the terminal text instead of making an image of text. Images are bad for accessibility, are harder to read, take up more space, and can't be copied from so it can be more work to make an answer and lessens your chance to get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem

You forgot the `-pattern_type glob` input option. As a result `ffmpeg` expanded the wildcard (`*`) and interpreted `image0000.jpg` as the only input and all of the following images as outputs. The command was executed as:

```
ffmpeg -i Timelapse/image0000.jpg Timelapse/image0001.jpg Timelapse/image0002.jpg Timelapse/image0003.jpg [...] -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 0 output.mkv -y
```

Because you used `-y` it overwrote all of the output images without asking you for confirmation.

## Solution

Using the *glob pattern*:

```
ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -i 'Timelapse/*.jpg' -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 0 output.mkv
```

Or using the *sequence pattern* which can also be used on Windows:

```
ffmpeg -i Timelapse/image%04d.jpg -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 0 output.mkv
```

See [FFmpeg image demuxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1) for more info.

Comment: Understood regarding copying the output rather than screenshotting.

Your suggestion worked! 

Only issue now is the video will flash every 5ish frames with the same image each time. I believe that is because I overwrote the files every time I attempted it with my original code. 

Thank you for your help.